# Implementing a rayon::iter::ParallelIterator

Tags: rust, rayon

I'm rather new to Rust, but managed to successfully use [Rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.2.1/rayon/index.html) to process data in parallel. At least as long as I'm working on existing data structures and `par_iter()` works out of the box. Now I have implemented my own `struct` which also implements `Iterator`:

```
struct TaskQueue {
      // ...
}

impl Iterator for TaskQueue {
    type Item = QueueItem;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<QueueItem> {
         // ...
    }
}
```

That code works fine for a plain `for item in queue_instance {...}` loop. I hoped, that this enough to get Rayon working with my code, but that's not the case. I have to implement a [ParallelIterator](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.2.1/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html). Based on the docs I tried

```
impl ParallelIterator for TaskQueue {
    type Item = QueueItem;

    fn drive_unindexed<C>(self, consumer: C) -> C::Result
        where C: UnindexedConsumer<QueueItem>
    {
        self.next().unwrap()
    }
}
```

The compiler tells me

> expected `<C as rayon::iter::plumbing::Consumer<QueueItem>>::Result`
>   because of return type

with the following hint:

> note: expected type `<C as rayon::iter::plumbing::Consumer<QueueItem>>::Result` found type `QueueItem`
>
> note: consider constraining the associated type `<C as rayon::iter::plumbing::Consumer<QueueItem>>::Result` to `QueueItem` or calling a method that returns `<C as rayon::iter::plumbing::Consumer<QueueItem>>::Result`
>
> note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html

To my understanding `::Result` should be `QueueItem` and I could not (yet) make much sense out of the chapter about advanced traits. How do I have to implement the `drive_unindexed` function to get my code working with Rayon?

Comment: You need to add a constraint stating that `C::Result = QueueItem`

Comment: Could you add a few more details where and how to do that? I tried it in the where clause, but get an `expected trait, found struct `QueueItem`: not a trait` error.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you are asking for, but fastest solution would be using https://docs.rs/rayon/1.2.1/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelBridge.html, which turns every Iterator into ParIter.

Comment: @dotPoozer it is not exactly the answer to my question, but the perfect solution for my problem. Thanks!